# Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare() [xamarin]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So i don't actually have a question because i've already solved it, but in case someone else runs into this issue it's always nice to have a neat solution.

And while there is a plentitude of `"Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare()"` - questions there is none tagged with xamarin. (so theirs is all java and i had 0 matches for "Can't create handler inside thread which has not called Looper.prepare() [xamarin]")

Answer (score 20):

The issue is generated because You tried to do work on UI from other thread. If you want to change UI, Must call UI changes from UI thread.

Xamarin Android:

```
activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
      // Write your code here         
});
```

Xamarin IOS:

```
nsObject.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     // Write your code here                
});
```

Xamarin Forms:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
     // Write your code here
});
```

Answer (score 13):

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static Task<bool> DisplayAlertOnUi(this Page source, string title, string message, string accept, string cancel)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> doneSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await source.DisplayAlert(title, message, accept, cancel);
                doneSource.SetResult(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                doneSource.SetException(ex);
            }
        });

        return doneSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Finally i had a case for using TaskCompletionSource to solve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar actually happend to me. Previous evening I was developing and testing my app. Next morning, from other computer I got the exception you described. I was remembered from a official `Xamarin.Forms` documentation that sometimes a **bin and obj** **folder removal** solves lot of issues.

I did exactly the same, **removed my** **bin** **and obj folder** from my shared Xamarin.Forms library and also from Xamarin.Android library.

The strange exception disappeared.