# Xamarin Forms, ScrollView ScrollToAsync Speed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, scrollview, renderer

Anyone knows how to change the speed of the scroll animation in ScrollToAsync method for Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView control?

I'm developing an Android App with Xamarin Forms.
Thanks

Comment: You could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648006/how-to-set-animation-speed-of-scrolltoasyncelement-scrolltoposition-boolean

Comment: Thanks @YorkShen-MSFT , finally i've made a mix between FadeTo & ScrollToAsync. I explain it in the answer below.

Comment: Happy coding. : )

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the ScrollToAsync speed is hardcoded to 1000 ms ([at least for Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/3c14c064257178acf4a843daff422ab8aa9cde10/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ScrollViewRenderer.cs#L388)).

I was able to work around this by just animating the scroll myself:

```
Point point = scrollView.GetScrollPositionForElement(targetElement, ScrollToPosition.Start);

var animation = new Animation(
    callback: y => scrollView.ScrollToAsync(point.X, y, animated: false),
    start: scrollView.ScrollY,
    end: point.Y - 6);
animation.Commit(
    owner: this,
    name: "Scroll",
    length: 300,
    easing: Easing.CubicIn);
```

And [here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.animation?view=xamarin-forms) for animation.

Comment: This works perfectly on android & ios.I prefere Easing.SinInOut

Comment: What is the reason for the `-6`?

Comment: Note that this answer covers how to animate _vertically_. It took me a few moments to realize that. If you require _horizontal scrolling_, see [my answer further below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053001/2550406)

Answer (score 4):

Modified from [Taylor Lafrinere's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54441859/2550406), here is the same snippet as a *horizontal* scroll animation:

```
Point point = scrollView.GetScrollPositionForElement(screenContent, ScrollToPosition.Start);

// insert fix for iOS jumping here

var animation = new Animation(
    callback: x => scrollView.ScrollToAsync(x, point.Y, animated: false),
    start: scrollView.ScrollX,
    end: point.X);

animation.Commit(
    owner: this,
    name: "Scroll",
    length: 300,
    easing: Easing.CubicIn);
```

It is worth pointing out that on iOS, this code displaced the view also towards the top. Something which you do not want. I believe the reason for this is that iOS understands the input for the animation as the lower edge of the scrollview whereas Android understands it as the *upper* edge of the scrollview.
To avoid this jump, set `point.Y` to 0 on iOS:

```
// iOS seems to understand the input for the animation as the lower edge of the scrollview
// Android the upper edge.
if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform == Xamarin.Forms.Device.iOS) 
   {
       point.Y = 0;
   }
```

---

<sub>I still think this answer should have been an edit, but since it was rejected as "Should be an answer or a comment" and it certainly cannot be a comment, here it is as an answer. The intent is to make it more clear that Taylor's Answer covers the vertical animation, and to show how to do a horizontal one instead.</sub>

Comment: I just keep getting errors with any of this code `'Animators may only be run on Looper threads'` How on earth did you get this to run?

Comment: @Jammer I'm no longer working at the company who I used this for, so I cannot check the code. But if the error message is that, perhaps I have run it in such a "looper thread". First thing I would try is calling it from the main thread and not some background thread.Possibly helpful to you: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148333/2550406) [link2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/176669/animators-may-only-be-run-on-looper-threads) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50264987/looper-threads-issue-but-not-using-animator)

Comment: Yeah I tried this just after posting, it got around this error but still didn't work. WIll check your links and thanks for the reply, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the increase of speed of AsyncToScroll I've used the FadeTo method of scrollview and set the parameter "animated" of AsyncToScroll to false. (My example is for an horizontal scrollview)

```
await MyScrollView.FadeTo(1, 200, Easing.CubicIn);
await MyScrollView.ScrollToAsync(_newScrollX_value, 0, false);
```